# Set max date from date1 to date2 up to 365 days

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date

I have 2 jQuery datepickers:

```
<p><label>Start Date:</label> </p><p>
    <input type="text" id="date1" name="date1" class="date-pick smallInput required"/>
    </p>

    <p><label>End Date:</label> </p><p>
    <input type="text" id="date2" name="date2" class="date-pick smallInput required"/>* 
    </p>

    <p><label>Total Period:</label> </p><p>
    <input type="text" id="Total_Period" name="Total_Period" class="smallInput required"/> * 
    </p>
```

I need help with writing some code for the following:

1. date2 cannot be more than 365 days after date1
2. Calculate amount of days between date1 and date2 in Total_Period

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the difference between two dates that are set to the same time in whole days, subtract one from the other and divide by the milliseconds in one day, then round to the nearest whole day (accounts for daylight saving):

```
function diffInDays(d0, d1) {
  var msDay   = 8.64e7;          // ms in 1 day
  var msLimit = 3.1536e10;       // ms in 365 days

  var diff = Math.abs(d1 - d0);  // diff in ms

  if (diff > msLimit) {
    return false;        // or throw error or whatever
  }

  // Return number of days
  // Rounding removes daylight saving effect +/- 1 hour
  return Math.round(diff / msDay);
}
```

Note that this depends on how you measure a day. If the dates have the same time (say 00:00:00.0) then the above "works". However, if they have different times then it may not. E.g. should the difference between 2014-07-25 23:59:59 and  2014-07-26 00:00:01 be one day or 2 seconds (0 days)?

If the times might be different but you want to only deal with dates (i.e. the difference above is 1 day not 0 days), then copy the dates and set their time to the same time:

```
function diffInDays(d0, d1) {
  // Copy dates so don't affect originals
  d0 = new Date(+d0);
  d1 = new Date(+d1);

  // Set to same time, midnight at start of day
  d0.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  d1.setHours(0,0,0,0);

  // rest of function is as above
  ...
}

console.log(diffInDays(new Date(2014,6,25,23,59,59), new Date(2014,6,26,0,0,1))); // 1
console.log(diffInDays(new Date(2014,0,1), new Date(2014,11,31)));  // 364
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p><label>End Date:</label> </p><p>
<input type="text" id="date1" oninput="validate1()" name="date2" class="date-pick smallInput required"/>*

</p>
<p><label>End Date:</label> </p><p>

<input type="text" id="date2" oninput="validate2()" name="date2" class="date-pick smallInput required"/>* 

</p>

<p><label>Total Period:</label> </p><p>
<input type="text" id="Total_Period" name="Total_Period" class="smallInput required"/> *    </p>
```

in your javascript

copy paste this function and just change a few thing for date2..

second is

```
function totalday()
{
var a =document.getElementById('date1');
var b =document.getElementById('date2');
var a =document.getElementById(total_period).value= a-b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/g2sws/)**

JS code:

```
 $(function () {
     var days_difference = 365;

    function addDays(theDate, days) {
        return new Date(theDate.getTime() + days*24*60*60*1000);
    }
    function subtractDays(theDate, days) {
        return new Date(theDate.getTime() - days*24*60*60*1000);
    } 
    function parseDate(str) {
        var mdy = str.split('/')
        return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[0]-1, mdy[1]);
    }

    function generate_difference()
    {
        var from_date = $("#from").datepicker( "getDate" );
        var to_date = $("#to").datepicker( "getDate" );

        //alert("In generate_difference \n From date = "+from_date+" \n To date = "+to_date);

            if(from_date != null && to_date != null)
            {
                var diff_days = (to_date-from_date)/(1000*60*60*24);
                $('#diff_days').val(diff_days);
            }
    }

     $("#from").datepicker({
         //defaultDate: "+1w",
         changeMonth: true,
         //numberOfMonths: 3,
         onClose: function (selectedDate) {
             //The selectedDate is in format mm/dd/yyyy so it should be convert to a valid javascript date
             selectedDate = parseDate(selectedDate);

             //alert("selectedDate = "+selectedDate+" parsed date = "+parseDate(selectedDate)+" new parsed = "+Date.parse(selectedDate));

             //Generate a new date by adding "no. of days i.e 365" to selected date
             var new_date = addDays(selectedDate, days_difference);

             //alert("selectedDate = "+selectedDate+" new_date = "+new_date);


             $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
             $("#to").datepicker("option", "maxDate", new_date);

             generate_difference();
         }
     });
     $("#to").datepicker({
         //defaultDate: "+1w",
         changeMonth: true,
         //numberOfMonths: 3,
         onClose: function (selectedDate) {
             selectedDate = parseDate(selectedDate);

             var new_date = subtractDays(selectedDate, days_difference)
             //alert("selectedDate = "+selectedDate+" new_date = "+new_date);
             $("#from").datepicker("option", "minDate", new_date);
             $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);

             generate_difference();
         }
     });
 });
```